# In Google Script how can I get feedback from the user during runtime?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

I'm attempting to get user feedback during runtime of a Google Script.  I want the user to be able to select one or more students from a list of names and also select one or more standards from a list of standards.

I attempted to do this by creating an html popup screen with  boxes.  The popup works fine, but I can't gain access to the results of the popup.

[Sample](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_4lzj315SVMHhJRjrN7ydPGi8oCX4bB24GDD-2FRYBs/edit?usp=sharing)

Here are my current script files:

code.gs

```
// Use this code for Google Docs, Forms, or new Sheets.
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
      .createMenu('Dialog')
      .addItem('Open', 'doGet')
      .addToUi();
}

function doGet() {
  html = HtmlService
       .createTemplateFromFile('Index')
       .evaluate()
       .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);


  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
      .showModalDialog(html, 'Dialog title');
}

function getStandards(){
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(2,1,15,1);

  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  return data;

}

function getStudents(){
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(2,2,15,1);

  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  return data;

}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>

Standards?   Students?
<br>
<select size="15"   name="standards" multiple>
    <? var data = getStandards();
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { ?>
        <option><?= data[i] ?>
    <? } ?> 
</select>

<select size="15"   name="students" multiple>

    <? var data = getStudents();
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { ?>
        <option><?= data[i] ?>
    <? } ?>
</select>

    <input type="button" value="Close"
        onclick="google.script.host.close()" />


</body>
</html>
```

[image: Image of form]

This is the form that is displayed, but I need to get the list of Standards and the list of Students when I hit the close button so that I can Create a bunch of new rows in my spreadsheet.

The target result would be to have 9 new rows added.  One for each student/standard pair.  Then I can add scores for each one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't mean to sound weird but why not just use Google form? it automatically puts all the entries into the Google Sheet.

Comment: This is just a small part of a larger spreadsheet.  Basically I'm trying to add data to a spreadsheet.  This form will allow me to add a bunch of rows at once rather than one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

At some point before the `.close()` happens you'll want to add in some thing like:

```
<input type="button" value="Close"
  onclick="
    google.script.run.storeInput
    (
      [
        document.getElementById("#standards").value,
        document.getElementById("#students").value
      ]
    )
   google.script.host.close()" />
```

After adding an ID attribute to both selects and creating a `function storeInput(arr)` in .gs